# BaseAdapter not allow INTENT action

Tags: android

An extended class with `BaseAdapter` will not allow me to jump from one activity to the second :: 
it give me syntax error ::

```
holder.capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {                   
    intent_request = new Intent(this, SaxParser2.class);
}
```

**Screen**

[image]

Comment: Look at my answer properly, I have a written line in BOLD characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this line,

```
intent_request = new Intent(this, SaxParser2.class);
```

to

```
intent_request = new Intent(<Activity name>.this, SaxParser2.class);
```

**In your case you should have to context of the activity from which you call your base adapter class's constructor,**

using that context of activity,

```
 intent_request = new Intent(context, SaxParser2.class);
```

then,

```
 context.StartActivity(intent_request);
```

NOTE: `I guess SaxParser2 is a activity not a class.`

Comment: ya you a right it is activity and i need to call activity only, i have tried that but now problem in `StartActivity(intent_request);`

Comment: it not allow me to implement method `startActivity`

Comment: startActivity() is method of activity class so you can use it with activity context only in your base adapter class, so it should be activityContext.startActivity(intent_request);